# Excel VBA- Msgbox when cell A= Yes and Cell B= No

Tags: vba, excel

I've been having a hard time trying to find a VBA code that will have a msgbox popup if for example Cell A1 is "Yes" and when Cell B1's answer is "No", a message box will pop up to review the answer in Cell B1. Both cells will both have dropdowns so the only possible answers are "Yes" and "No"

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure exactly what are you trying to achieve here but if you have drop downs in column A and B with items "Yes" and "No" and after selecting items in column A & B, all you want to compare the items selected in column A and B to see if different items are selected, place the following code on sheet module.

To do so follow these steps....

1) Right click the Sheet Tab --> View Code --> Place the code given below into the opened code window.

2) Close VB Editor and save your workbook as Macro-Enabled Workbook.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
Dim r As Long
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:B")) Is Nothing Then
    r = Target.Row
    If Cells(r, "A") <> "" And Cells(r, "B") <> "" Then
        If Cells(r, "A") <> Cells(r, "B") Then
            MsgBox "Answers provided in column A and B in Row " & r & " don't match.", vbExclamation, "Different Answers!"
        End If
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You're welcome Didi! Glad it worked as per expectation. Please take a moment to accept the answer to mark your question as Solved. :)

Comment: Hi Sktneer, is there a way to change the code so it's not case sensitive? Thanks!

Comment: Just change the IF statement like this: If LCase(Cells(r, "A")) <> LCase(Cells(r, "B")) Then